# React Query and dealing with same behavior of queries in multiple files

Tags: react-query

This is more of an architectural question. When I was using redux-sages, I could just have a "worker saga" that made my api calls (yields) and when my 3 pages that needed this bahavior, I would just apply a case for it, and it would run on those pages.

But I moved away from all that and am now using react-query. But I am curious how people are dealing with, lets say, I have 3 custom useQuery calls... how are you consolidating them to include them INTO a couple pages, so you don't have to dupe that work?

So, lets say right now I have in fileA:

```
   const { status, data: { plans} } = useCustomQuery1();

   const { data: { client } } = useCustomQuery2({});
   const {
    data: { prices } = {} } = useCustomQuery3({
      enabled: client.id,
      id: client.id,
   });
   /* refetch: call later */
   const {refetch } = useCustomQuery3({
    id: client.id,
    config: {
      enabled: false
    }
  });
```

so, in my "fileA", I can get at refetch/prrices/plans/status etc... BUT, if I extract this out, so I use another "queries.js" file and name ala....

```
 // queries.js
 const useMySharedQueries1 = () => {

    const { status, data: { plans} } = useCustomQuery1();

    const { data: { client } } = useCustomQuery2({});
    const {
      data: { prices } = {} } = useCustomQuery3({
      enabled: client.id,
      id: client.id,
    });
   /* refetch: call later */
   const {refetch } = useCustomQuery3({
     id: client.id,
     config: {
     enabled: false
   }
   });

  return {
    refetch, prices, plans
  }
```

}

I feel like there is a better way, more robust and succinct way to achieve this? Would I use "useQueries", but then does that deal with "refetch" queires or ones that need "enabled" etc.. and what about returning "all that data" so the consuming pages can use it?

Comment: Did you end up resolving this?

Comment: No, I just left it for now. I guess I could just add a another conditional return ala "if (loaded1 && loaded2 and loaded2) return {....all the data } else return {}
BUT, have you experimented and come up with something?